# Date cannot be pasted on chrome with using VBA - Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, date

I can change date on web page if I use internet explorer with below code(code1). 
however, I changed browser to chrome with selenium. (as code 2), date section on web page is changed but it is partial.
for example: date is set 18/02/2020 on web page when it is opened. then I want to change date as 01/03/2017 but it is changed to 03/02/2017. that means, month section in macro shanged the date section, nothing changed on month section and year section is also changed

i have tried to change date order in macro like mm/dd/yyyy but ı cant get a proper date solution. just tried millions of code and still cannot find anything.

so please help me to change date section on chrome with using selenium.
Sheet1.Range("A1") = 01/03/2017
Code1

```
ie.document.getElementsByName("date$From")(0).Value = Sheet1.Range("A1").Text
```

Code2 (selenium and VBA)

```
obj.FindElementById("date_From").SendKeys (sheet1.Range("A1")).Text
```

Website code (website is behind a firewall)

```
<input name="date$From" type="text" value="18/02/2020" size="6" id="date_tbFrom" class="searchSelect">
<input type="hidden" name="date_From_Client" id="date_From_Client">
```

Comment: same result. nothing changed. still date is wrong

Comment: Assuming `obj` is a reference to the Selenium driver, this should do it:  `obj.FindElementById("date_tbFrom").SendKeys(Sheet1.[a1].Text).Submit`

Comment: Did this update work for you>

Comment: @ExcelHero yes you are right obj. is webdriver. I have added submit and it gives "Server Error in '/' Application." error. by the way, when I changed date format form 01/03/2017 to 01,03,2017 date is adding normal but at that time everything works fine with debugging mode (F8) however,  adding nothing to date section with F5.

Comment: is there anyway to directly change the value on web page. `<input name="date$From" type="text" value="18/02/2020"` there is an obvious value if there is a way to just replace it, it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution bymelf with try it. I used tab button usage to reach date section and used date format as 01,01,2021. used comma (,) instead of slash (/) as date seperator.

```
obj.FindElementByName("date$From").Clear
obj.FindElementById("place_before_date").Click
obj.SendKeys (keys.Tab)
obj.FindElementById("date$From").SendKeys (Sheet1.Range("A" & x))
```